# Excel formula writing help - if function outputting difference calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to write a formula that will take one value in one column and subtract it from another value in another column IF values in same row but different column are +/- 80.

I want to subtract "Autumn View" column labelled " $ Total" from the "SUBJECT PROPERTY" column "$ Total." I want to subtract ONLY if values in Autumn View column "SF" are within +/- 80 of SUBJECT PROPERTY "SF" column.

Ideally I would also want to calculate this difference only if the values in both "unit type" columns match up with the SUBJECT PROP "unit type" columns.

Any guidance on writing a formula?

[image: excel screenshot - non confidential]

Answer (score 0):

The absolute value of the difference should be 80.
`=IF(`
      `AND( ABS(This-That) < 80;`
           `Unit_type=Subject_prop`
         `);`
    `do_the_calculation;`
    `do_nothing`
   `)`

That would be the essence of your answer;
I hope you do not need more than so,

;-)  <- smile.

Comment: Now, your data seems to be in different places, so some kind of `VLOOKUP(...)` would be necessary...